# I can't seem to link html to css

Tags: html, css

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="designpage" type="text/css">
    <title> Viktoria Niemann </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Dear Vik</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href= "index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/-LOVE-love-36983825-1680-1050.jpg">

  </body>
</html>
```

I am not sure why html is not linking to css. I think i have written a code correctly

Comment: Is `style.css` located in the same folder as your html file?

Comment: `rel` can't be `designpage`. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_rel.asp

Comment: HTML and CSS are cached, so make sure you flush the cache. Once you've done that, check the path to the CSS, use the developer tools, specifically the network tab, to see if the CSS resource is downloaded. Then change your path the the CSS to what it actually is, we can't tell you because we don't know your folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

make your rel "stylesheet" like this ------> rel="stylesheet"

```html
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: OP doesn't have `rel "stylesheet"`

Comment: what do you mean OP?

Comment: Original poster

Comment: you mean rel "designpage" is true here?

Comment: No. In your post you say `make your rel "stylesheet" rel="stylesheet"`, but (s)he doesn't have `rel "stylesheet"`, (s)he has `rel="designpage"`

Comment: I meant rel=" stylesheet" :\ acutually at first i was saying it without any syntax

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <title> Viktoria Niemann </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Dear Vik</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/-LOVE-love-36983825-1680-1050.jpg">

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your link tag(rel property) to

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Is Correct Your href Value?is your style sheet inside your doc?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your style.css is in the same folder as your HTML file.

since you are using directly the filename as path.

Answer (score 0):

to achieve this you would change the rel to stylesheet instead of designpage.
The rel is required because it specifies the relationship between the document you are working on and the document

```html
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```